# webkit css pseudo elements for time field

Tags: css, webkit, pseudo-element

I've found an interesting post about webkit pseudo elements for inputs [here](https://gist.github.com/afabbro/3759334), so I was going to remove the cancel button from input `type="time"`. But by murthy's law exactly this pseudo element is not described anywhere.

P.S. I already tryed

```
::-webkit-search-cancel-button
::-webkit-input-cancel-button 
::-webkit-time-cancel-button
::-webkit-time-cancel-button
```

Of course there is a way to do this with `:after` element, but I don't believe there is no pseudo element for this

```css
input[type="time"]::after
{
    content: "";
    background: #FFF;
    height: 20px;
    width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 -10px;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That would be `::-webkit-clear-button`

So use

```
input[type="time"]::-webkit-clear-button{
    display:none;
}
```

To find such things you can enable ***Show Shadow DOM*** from the console options, under ***Elements***.

This way when you select the `input` element, you can open it and look under the hood..

Comment: +1 for shadow DOM in inspector. I had never figured out what that option did (I didn't Google). And it's arguably easier than making a good guess and looking in the source code :p

Answer (score 3):

I knew that Internet Explorer 10 supports such a pseudo-element with `::-ms-clear`.
So I [searched](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#search/&q=webkit-clear&sq=package%3achromium&type=cs) in the source code of Chromium for "webkit-clear" and discovered the presence of `::-webkit-clear-button`.

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6LPvp/) shows that the `::-webkit-clear-button` pseudo-element has the desired effect.

```
input[type="time"]::-webkit-clear-button {
    display: none;
}
```