# Html5 input type="time" with an X button

Tags: html, google-chrome, input

I noticed that on Chrome HTML5 inputs with `type=time` have an X button that clears the value, setting it to the empty value `--:--`; however, this appears only when the input doesn't have the `required` attribute, and I can see the reason why this happens, since clearing out a required field shouldn't be allowed.

Is there any way, maybe through some CSS property I don't know of, to have the X button not display *without* setting the `required` attribute, for instance if I just don't want it to be visible but my field isn't, semantically, required?

This is what happens when the input doesn't have the `required` attribute:

[image: Not required]

And this is what happens when the `required` attribute is specified:

[image: Required]

Comment: The same question was asked a few hours ago in [webkit css pseudo elements for time field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17340038/webkit-css-pseudo-elements-for-time-field). See [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6LPvp/) from [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17340433/938089).

Comment: You're right, I voted for the closing, thanks.